# How did my program get to the output of 1

Tags: java, parameters

Alright so I am doing AP comp sci for high school and I am really confused on how this program got to A = 1 I do not see any declaration for x and y. Thanks

```
public class ClassA
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        ClassA n = new ClassA(1 , 2);  
        int a = 0;
        a = n.methodA(a);
        System.out.println("a =" + a);


    }
    private int myNum1;
    private int myNum2;
    public ClassA(int x, int y)   
    {
        myNum1 = x;
        myNum2 = y;
    }

    public int methodA(int y)
    {
        return myNum1+y;

    }

    public int getMyNum1()
    {
        return myNum1;

    }

    public int getMyNum2()
    {
        return myNum2;
    }
}
```

Comment: `int x, int y` - here's the declaration.

Comment: Because of the constructor of ClassA, `new ClassA(1 , 2);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't actually matter what you use as parameters for your constructor. You create `a` and set it to 0, then set `a` to `n.methodA(a)` where the parameter `a` is 0, which returns 1.

You could use any values for your constructor call and it `n.methodA(a)` would always return 1.

Search for "java visualizer" online for a nice tool that can help you understand what your program does step by step.

Comment: How did y get 0 then? Didn't I declare y as 0. Isn't y =2 because of new ClassA(1 , 2);

Answer (score 0):

When you do  `ClassA n = new ClassA(1 , 2);` `myNum1` will be become 1 and `myNum2` becomes 2 for the object `n`.

Now when you call `n.methodA(a)` you are essentially calling `n.methodA(0)` and according to the definition of the `methodA`, it will return `myNum1+0 => 1+0 => 1`

Comment: How did y get 0? Didn't I declare y as 0? Isn't y =2 because of new ClassA(1 , 2);

Answer (score 0):

Here's what your code is doing..

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    ClassA n = new ClassA(1 , 2); // x = 1, y = 2
    int a = 0;
    a = n.methodA(a); // a = 1 + 0 = n.Method(a = 0) 
    System.out.println("a =" + a); // prints a = 1


}


 /** remember that myNum1 = x = 1, as stated in 
ClassA n = new ClassA(1 , 2) **/

public int methodA(int y) // int y = a = 0
{
    return myNum1+y; // return (myNum1* + y = 1 + 0)

}
```

`n.Method(a)` will return **1** (because 0+1 = 1), which prints `a = 1`